# C error TLS error

Tags: c

My Error

```
/usr/bin/ld: errno: TLS definition in /lib/libc.so.6 section .tbss
mismatches non-TLS reference in ./../lib/lib.a(file_op.o)
/lib/libc.so.6: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

Comment: A little bit of context, please?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.opencascade.org/org/forum/thread_9224/) says:

> What you need to do is this: open the
>   appropriate makefile (i.e. in `TKIGES`),
>   find the line `DEFAULT_INCLUDES`, and
>   add `-include /usr/include/errno.h` to
>   the end.

Your question is very vague, but perhaps that applies to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `extern int errno;` as `#include <errno.h>`.

Please see note in [this page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html):

> It was common in traditional C to declare errno manually (i.e.,
>   extern int errno) instead of including .  Do not do this.
>   It will not work with modern versions of the C library.  However, on
>   (very) old UNIX systems, there may be no  and the
>   declaration is needed.